# OpenWhisk Ngnix Pod CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers, openwhisk

I am very new to OpenWhisk and have some difficulties in the setup. 
The Ngnix Pod is running in a CrashLoopBackOff because of an error in the Pod.

```
2018/07/02 16:14:27 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in resolver "kube-dns.kube-system" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:41
nginx: [emerg] host not found in resolver "kube-dns.kube-system" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:41
```

I cannot jump into the Pod itself but I ran a Docker Container with the same Image the Pod is using and looked inside the nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

When I looked into the conf.d directory I found a single default.conf file in which the server_name was set to localhost:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

I believe this is causing the Issue and that the kube.dns service cannot resolv localhost.

However I do not know how I can resolve this Issue or at least work around it.
Maybe I can set a static hostname for the Pod in the Ngnix Deployment and enter that hostname into the ngnix config?

Could Someone provide a workaround too me or even a fix?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the "OpenWhisk Deployment on Kubernetes (https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-deploy-kube) project?

I suspect you may be hitting the Kubernetes bug described in the [README.md](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/README.md):

> However, multiple minor releases of Kubernetes, including 1.8.9 and 1.9.4 will not work for OpenWhisk due to bugs with volume mount subpaths (see[[1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61076)]). This bug will surface as a failure when deploying the nginx container.

The fix for this is using a version of Kubernetes that does not have the volume mount subpath bug.

Comment: Hi, I am using Kubernetes version 1.10, is this bug still occurring there? Seems like the bug should be fixed in 1.10.  I'll try downgrading to Kubernetes 1.8 and report back if it worked.

Comment: So, I did not need to downgrade to Kubernetes 1.8. The Bug was not the problem, the problem was that I used a custom cluster-dns in kubernetes. It seems that some of the components (invoker, kafka, controller) won't pull the custom configuration from kubelet-dns-args or w/e. Might want to check that.

Know I just need to know how I can configure the docker-pull-runtimes init container (inside the invoker pods (1 per node)) to use a proxy since I am behind my corporate proxy.

Comment: @rootdoot "docker-pull-runtimes init container to use proxy" - what you mean? As I understood, your Kubernetes can pull images, because you run the application.

Comment: The docker-pull-runtimes Container inside the Invoke Pod pulls various images (Actions) from https://hub.docker.com/u/openwhisk/. Since my Cluster sits behind a corporate Browser, I need a way to tell the Container to use a proxy. If I understand this right of course.

Answer (score 1):

kubeadm gets and checks environment from your currently running host OS session.

You can check if proxy has been set by executing the below command:

```
env | grep _proxy
```

In environments where a proxy server is configured to access the internet services, such as the Docker Hub or the Oracle Container Registry, you may need to perform several configuration steps to get Kubernetes to install and to run correctly.

- Ensure that the Docker engine startup configuration on each node in the cluster is configured to use the proxy server. For instance, create a systemd service drop-in file at /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf with the following contents:

  `[Service]`

  `Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"`
  `Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"`

  Replace http://proxy.example.com:80/ with the URL for your HTTP proxy service. If you have an HTTPS proxy and you have specified this as well, replace https://proxy.example.com:443/ with the URL and port for this service. If you have made a change to your Docker systemd service configuration, run the following commands:

  `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart docker`
- You may need to set the http_proxy or https_proxy environment variables to be able to run other commands on any of the nodes in your cluster. For example:

  `export http_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:80/"`

  `export https_proxy="https://proxy.example.com:443/"`
- Disable the proxy configuration for the localhost and any node IPs in the cluster:

  `export no_proxy="127.0.0.1, 192.0.2.10, 192.0.2.11, 192.0.2.12"`

These steps should be sufficient to enable the deployment to function normally. Use of a transparent proxy that does not require configuration on the host and which ignores internal network requests, can reduce the complexity of the configuration and may help to avoid unexpected behavior.